# не верный вывод в DOM jquery

Tags: html, jquery

Вот пример моего кода:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".titleNews").keyup(function (){
        if($(this).val() == "") {
            $(this).after('enter title news!!!');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Enter your name: <input class="titleNews" type="text">

<p>Enter your name in the input field above. It will change background color on keydown and keyup.</p>
```

Из него видно, что при таком написании - ошибка выводится столько раз подряд, сколько нажали на кнопку удаления текста в поле. Как сделать, чтоб эта ошибка появлялась только 1 раз и чтоб проверка поля была даже если туда ничего не ввели а сразу нажали на submit?

Comment: ну сделай ты элемент например span с классом error и выводи сообщение туда

Comment: я сделал уже элемент р и выводится в него понескольку раз! введи несколько раз кнопкой интер в пустое поле и поймешь сразу

Comment: ты выводишь не в `p`, ты выводишь в `body`.... в `p` у тебя только надпись про `Enter your name in the input field above` ......еще раз говорю, сделай тег и выводи туда.....не через `after`, а просто текстом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заведи тег с классом `error` и складывай туда текст ошибки и выводи:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var errorMsg = "";
    $(".titleNews").keyup(function (){
        errorMsg = $(this).val().trim() == "" ? 'enter title news!!!' : "";    
        $('.error').text(errorMsg);        
    });
});
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Enter your name: <input class="titleNews" type="text">
<span class="error"></span>
<p>Enter your name in the input field above. It will change background color on keydown and keyup.</p>
```